# Using Excel Data Reader

Tags: c#, excel, database, datareader

I created a project and used the library, and when I execute the project in Visual 2019, there is no problem, but when creating the exe file, it shows the following: could not load file or assembly exceldatareader version 3.7.0.0 this system cannot find "

Comment: How are you creating the exe? Did you check this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/?

Comment: I will check again